# Complement of a tree $T$

Tags: graph-theory

Let $T$ be a tree having $n$ nodes with $n\geq 2$. Show that if the complement of $T$ is also a tree, then $n=4$. Note that if $T = (V,E)$ is a tree, then the complement of $T$ is $\overline{T} = (V,K\setminus E)$, where $K$ consists of all 2-element subsets of $V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: (i) If $T$ is a tree with $n$ vertices, then the number of edges is $e=n-1$.

(ii) Since the union of a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices and its complement $\bar{G}$ is the complete graph $K_n$, the number of edges of $\bar{G}$
is equal to $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}-e$, where $e$ is the number of edges in $G$.